# Dynamically generate site navigation from JSON with Backbone.Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to build my navigation based upon the contents of a JSON object returned by a REST API. I've been looking at trying to adapt [David Sulc's](http://davidsulc.com/blog/2012/04/15/a-simple-backbone-marionette-tutorial/) tutorial, but am running into a bit of a blocker somewhere.

My app uses the following basic structure:

```
  window.Foo = {
    Routers: {},
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Controllers: {}
  };

  Foo.App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application({});

  Foo.App.addRegions({
    navRegion: '#nav-wrapper'
  });

  Foo.App.on("initialize:after", function(options){
    if (Backbone.history){
      Backbone.history.start();
    }
  });

  /* MODELS & COLLECTIONS */

  // Nav
  Foo.Models.Nav = Backbone.Model.extend({});

  Foo.Collections.Nav = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Foo.Models.Nav,
    url: '/static/js/data/nav.json'

  });

  /* VIEWS */
  Foo.Views.NavLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    className: 'scroll',
    template: navTemplate,
    regions: {
      'primary': '#primary-nav'
    }
  });

  Foo.Views.navItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    template: navItemTemplate
  });

  Foo.Views.PrimaryNav = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    itemView: Foo.Views.navItemView
  });

  /* CONTROLLER */
  Foo.Controllers.Controller = {

    navLayout: new Foo.Views.NavLayout(),
    primaryNav: new Foo.Views.PrimaryNav({collection: Foo.navCollection}),

    home: function() {

      Foo.App.navRegion.show(this.navLayout);
      this.navLayout.primary.show(this.primaryNav);

    }
  }

  /* ROUTER */
  Foo.Routers.Router = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    controller: Foo.Controllers.Controller,

    appRoutes: {
      '': 'home'
    }
  });

  /* INITIALIZER */
  Foo.App.addInitializer(function(options) {
    Foo.navCollection = new Foo.Collections.Nav();
    Foo.navCollection.fetch();

    Foo.router = new Foo.Routers.Router();
  });

  return Foo;
```

Everything appears to be working as it should, except the Foo.Views.navItemView never gets rendered into the PrimaryNav view. I can see the JSON getting successfully loaded in the console, but only the containing UL (Foo.Views.PrimaryNav) gets rendered. I'm clearly missing a step somewhere between fetching the collection and showing the view in my controller.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
So I reworked my app structure and moved the Nav collection stuff out of my addInitializer and into the Controller and now it's working. Updated simplified structure:

```
  window.Foo = {
    Routers: {},
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Controllers: {}
  };

  Foo.App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application({});

  Foo.App.addRegions({
    navRegion: '#nav-wrapper'
  });

  Foo.App.on('initialize:after', function(options){
    if (Backbone.history){
      Backbone.history.start();
    }
  });

  /* MODELS & COLLECTIONS */

  // Nav
  Foo.Models.Nav = Backbone.Model.extend();

  Foo.Collections.PNav = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Foo.Models.Nav,
    url: '/static/js/data/primary-nav.json'
  });


  /* VIEWS */

  // Nav
  Foo.Views.NavLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    className: 'scroll',
    template: navTemplate,
    regions: {
      'primary': '#primary-nav',
      'favourites': '#favourites-nav'
    }
  });

  Foo.Views.navItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    model: Foo.Models.Nav,
    tagName: 'li',
    template: navItemTemplate
  });

  Foo.Views.PrimaryNav = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    itemView: Foo.Views.navItemView
  });

  /* CONTROLLER */
  Foo.Controllers.Controller = {
    setupHasRun: false,

    setup: function() {

      var navLayout = new Foo.Views.NavLayout(),
        primaryNavCollection = new Foo.Collections.PNav(),
        primaryNavFetch = primaryNavCollection.fetch({async: false}),
        primaryNav = new Foo.Views.PrimaryNav({collection: primaryNavCollection}),

      Foo.App.navRegion.show(navLayout);
      navLayout.primary.show(primaryNav);

      this.setupHasRun = true;
    }
  }

  /* ROUTER */
  Foo.Routers.Router = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    controller: Foo.Controllers.Controller,

    appRoutes: {
      // Home
      '': 'home'
    }
  });

  /* INITIALIZER */
  Foo.App.addInitializer(function(options) {

    Foo.router = new Foo.Routers.Router();

    contentPanes();
  });

  return Foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

David Sulc wrote a book on Marionette, check the git repo of the example in the book.

https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction

From your code I would recommend to organize the code on modules as in the example, and not in a global object as you do.

Then each module will have a controller and you can use them to navigate all parts of the application.

Also check out official docs in Marionette repo.

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/tree/master/docs